# My H-bridge can't control my 3v motor

Tags: arduino, h-bridge

I'm trying to control my 3v motor from my 5v arduino.

For this i use :

- 5 volt power source from pc for the arduino
- L9110 H-bridge module
- 2 AA Battery as power source for the L9110 H-bridge

Here is the setup :[image]

however if I touch the h-bridge pin with the 5v source from the arduino (red cable on the image), nothing happens....

Any idea ? if I power the motor directly from the battery, the motor works

Maybe the problem is that I have 2 different power source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to complete a circuit in order for the current to flow. Creating a common ground between the power sources (connecting the grounds together) should fix the problem.